# PHP echo appears to work but doesnt show up in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use a php script to generate HTML in order to save lines and what not. I am using jQuery to call my php and then put the result into a specified div as shown below:

```
function createSidebarRow(div, cellNum, rowName, rowDesc) {
            $("#" + div).load("createIndexSidebarRow.php?cellNum=" + cellNum + "&rowName=" + rowName + "&rowDesc=" + rowDesc);
        }
```

However, when this is executed the HTML is not updated on the page, I can see that the code has worked because the browser network activity confirms it. I am trying to figure out what is causing it to not update.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8n4Z.jpg) is the network activity confirming the echo'd HTML.

Comment: check if your selector is correct and can you put the script in the footer so that it executes after html is loaded or simply call the function inside $(document).ready(function());

Comment: are you trying to add <td> directly inside div ?

Comment: @Arjun, yes I am trying to do so, would this cause an issue?

Comment: its not correct to add it like that. you would face browser compatibility issue.

Comment: @Arjun, ah okay I have changed it to be the other way around. A div within a TD object.

Comment: can u do console.log($("#" + div)) inside your function and see if your selector is correct

Comment: @Arjun, that produces this: [div#sidebar0, context: document, selector: "#sidebar0"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out jQuery doesn't play ball when you include spaces in the POST URL. I removed the space and used %20 instead and all is well now. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It might be so, that the div is not yet created in the DOM. (the div that should received the html).

Are you calling createSidebarRow directly on page load?

If so, put the function call in a document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    createSidebarRow (... );
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and I still get the same result, the function appears to work but no change in the HTML

Comment: What is the Content-Type the php file is returning? Is it set to text/html ?

Comment: It is text/html, yes

Comment: Try adding the html that php returns manually to the div. So $('#'+div).html('<b>your html</b>'); instead of the php call. What does that give you?

Comment: This does work correctly, I believe it may be an issue with my HTML output

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stating the obvious, but the div you are trying to fill up does exist with that particular id right?

If so, try this:

```
$("#" + div).load("createIndexSidebarRow.php?cellNum=" + cellNum + "&rowName=" + rowName + "&rowDesc=" + rowDesc, function() {
    alert('success');
});
```

If the id does exist (and it's unique) and you get an alert there should be no reason for it not to work.

Comment: Yes the div definitely does exist

Comment: and the alert, does it jingle jangle?

Comment: Yes it does appear